# How to make a wallpaper only show when unlocked?

Tags: macos, catalina, wallpaper

I don't really know if this is possible, but I wish to know how to do this. Basically, I just want to have my lock screen different from my actual wallpaper. Can you use a terminal command? Thanks in advance.